# Parsing telephone number from a SIP URI in Python

Tags: python, parsing, sip

Is `urlparse` the right module to use for this, or do we have something else?

```
>>> o = urlparse.urlparse('"User Name" <sips:+msisdn@domain?Accept-Contact=+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2e7671fd-31dd-1393-dkd6-835fe09f314f>";require;explicit>', scheme='sips')
>>> print o
ParseResult(scheme='sips', netloc='', path='"User Name" <sips:+msisdn@domain', params='', query='Accept-Contact=+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2e7671fd-31dd-1393-dkd6-835fe09f314f>";require;explicit>', fragment='')
>>>
```

I expected `+msisdn@domain` at `netloc` or `path`, but the value in `path` is a bit strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing a SIPS URI, but an Address-Of-Record (AOR). If you extract the URI from the AOR, you'll get:

```
>>> o = urlparse.urlparse('sips:+msisdn@domain?Accept-Contact=+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2e7671fd-31dd-1393-dkd6-835fe09f314f>";require;explicit')
>>> print o
ParseResult(scheme='sips', netloc='', path='+msisdn@domain', params='', query='Accept-Contact=+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2e7671fd-31dd-1393-dkd6-835fe09f314f>";require;explicit', fragment='')
```

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the `userinfo@host` part of the SIPS URI should go into the `path` component, so the result is correct here.

Answer (score 2):

You may look how this implemented in other libs, for example in *twisted*:
https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/protocols/sip.py#L427